# I need to login to a specific profile, not the default one outlook, despite provide username and password it still logon with default credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, outlook

I need to login to a specific profile

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder inboxFolder = null;
    oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
    oApp.Session.Logon("support@xx.com", "*******", false, true);
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace oNS = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    inboxFolder=oNS.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Namespace.Logon` takes the name of an existing profile (as shown in Control Panel | Mail | Show profiles), not an SMTP address.

The password parameter is not used at all. If you want to connect to a particular Exchange mailbox, you need to create a profile first. Note that if Outlook is already running, `Namespace.Logon` does nothing - Outlook will continue using the profile it loaded previously.

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) is an option (I am its author), it exposes [RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm).`LogonHostedExchangeMailbox` method that allows to connect to an Exchange 2013 or 2016 mailbox (including an Office 365 mailbox) as long as Basic Authentication is enabled.